# Wrong behavior of IF EXIST on a file in C:\Windows\System32 in Windows batch (Inno Setup)

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I'm trying to copy one Windows .dll file by using a batch script through Inno Setup.

Apparently, even though there is no `msvcr120.dll` file in `C:\Windows\System32` (I can confirm) I can only see *"file exists"*. 
Of course, I also tried to remove double quotation below.

```
if exist "C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll" (
    rem file exists
    echo  "file exists"
    pause
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
    copy %1\Utilities\msvcr120.dll  C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll
    echo  "file doesn't exist"
    pause
)
```

I checked it manually

```
C:\Users\changwon>dir /A:HS C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4A80-BDED

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32

File Not Found
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

## How to run a batch in Inno Setup

```
[Run]

Filename: "{app}\bin\Icacls\cacls.bat"; Parameters: """{app}"""
Filename: "{app}\Install\psql_init.bat"; Parameters: """{app}"""
```

## Other results

```
C:\Users\changwon>dir /A:L C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll
 Directory of C:\Windows\System32

File Not Found

C:\Users\changwon>where msvcr120.dll
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

## UPDATE

Windows 7 64bit and there is a msvcr120.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 instead.
But I'm trying to copy the file from my source dir to C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: Perhaps `msvcr120.dll` is hidden? try `dir /A:HS C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll`; or there is a directory with that name -- replace `/A:HS` by `/A:D` to test...

Comment: Updated question. I don't see the file. Actually, there was the file but for my testing, I renamed the original msvcr120.dll to msvcr120_backup.dll. My purpose is to copy the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe also try with `dir /A:L C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll` or `dir /S C:\Windows\msvcr120.*`; or type `where msvcr120.dll`...

Comment: OK, so the problem is as I described in my answer. Did you try the `64bit` flag?

Comment: Hold on second, genius. I'm testing with your advice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file probably exists in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Inno Setup is a 32-bit application. So by default, to run a batch file, it executes the 32-bit `cmd.exe`.

The 32-bit `cmd.exe`, when querying the `C:\Windows\System32`, [gets redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) to the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Read about [issues with 32-bit vs. 64-bit installations](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

---

If you are running the batch file using an entry in the `[Run]` section, use the [`64bit` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=64bit) to force execution of the 64-bit `cmd.exe`:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\bin\Icacls\cacls.bat"; Parameters: """{app}"""; Flags: 64bit
Filename: "{app}\Install\psql_init.bat"; Parameters: """{app}"""; Flags: 64bit
```

---

Though if it is a 32-bit DLL, you actually want it in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: PERFECT!!!! Yes, you're right. It was redirected. I need to copy 64bit version of the file. Now, my batch file detects that it doesn't exist and succeeded to copy!! Thank you so much!!