# Inno Setup Batch file Check for privileges using cacls fails

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I try to execute a batch file after setup finishes.

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C ""{app}\Start.bat"""; \
    Description: {cm:LaunchAfterInstallQuest_lbl}; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent shellexec;
```

The batch file `start.bat` is requesting administrative privileges and starts two services.

```
@if (1==1) @if(1==0) @ELSE
@echo off&SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"||(
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
    @goto :EOF
)

REM --> start services
set error=0
set date=%date%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

net start "SMC Integrationsserver" 2>>"%~dp0logfile_start_%date%.txt"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ( set error=1 )

net start "Wildfly" 2>>"%~dp0logfile_start_%date%.txt"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ( set error=1 )

if %error%==1 ( 
echo Ein Fehler trat auf, bitte pruefen Sie die Logdatei "%~dp0logfile_start_%date%.txt"
pause
@goto :EOF
)
if %error%==0 (
del /s /q "%~dp0logfile_*.txt"
)

@goto :EOF
@end @ELSE
ShA=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")
ShA.ShellExecute("cmd.exe","/c \""+WScript.ScriptFullName+"\"","","runas",1);
@end
```

When I click *Finish* in the setup installer, the `start.bat` file is executing in a infinite loop.

Any ideas what's wrong with it?

Comment: This such an overkill. Why do you request admin privileges in a batch file using such an ugly hack? Why don't you start the services from an elevated environment of the installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this such an overkill. Run the `net start` (or at least the batch file) directly form the `[Run]` section of the script, without the `postinstall` flag. This way the `net start` (or the batch file) is started with elevated privileges. And you do not need to use that ugly, error-prone and hardly debuggable hack with combining two languages in a single file.

Use "task" to make the run configurable by user.

---

Anyway, the batch file loops because the Inno Setup is 32-bit application, so it starts 32-bit `cmd.exe` by default, which cannot see the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\system` on 64-bit systems. That's because for 32-bit processes running on 64-bit systems, the `C:\WINDOWS\system32` is redirected to `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64`, where there's no `config` subdirectory. So the `cacls.exe` fails with

> The system cannot find the file specified.

---

See these question for details and solutions (hacks in your case):

- [Wrong behavior of IF EXIST on a file in C:\Windows\System32 in Windows batch (Inno Setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34878930/850848)
- [Install IIS with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33268900/850848)

Comment: Thank u Martin. What im trying to do, is to create a file to start and stop my two Services. The user can set the checkbox, to start the service after install or not, this is why i use `postinstall`  flag. With this file on the desktop every user can use it, but it needs elevated privileges to start the Service.

Comment: First, I believe this [answer to How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/850848) gives a better solution - And anyway, I've shown you how to fix your current script (or rather how to fix the way you run your current script).

Comment: Though in general, I'd use my suggested way (the task). And for the desktop shortcut, I would ideally use the "run as administrator" advanced property of the shortcut (but I admit, I do not know how to set it in Inno Setup).

Comment: I solved it with your last comment. U can set the flag "run as administrator" of the shortcut with innoSetup in the registry like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083187/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-launch-an-app-with-admin-privileges-from-the-cmd-lin)

Comment: Does it mean you can set the `AppCompatFlags` even for a batch file, not only .exe?